# SNMP v1 v2 v3 diffcences beetwen config files

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm learning about SNMP protocol. I wonder what changes in the configuration files can I make. What else can I add? How to distinguish between version 1 of 2c?

My snmpv1/v2c config file

```
rwcommunity  public
#trap
trapsink  localhost
authtrapenable  1
```

snmpv3 config file

```
createUser test MD5 "test12345" DES
rwuser  test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Net-SNMP Agent supports all three versions of the SNMP protocol. The version 1 and 2c are using a community string for simple authentication. This string is a shared secret between the agent and NMS. The string is passed in clear text over the network however and is not considered secure.

So from configuration perspective there are no differences between SNMPv1 and SNMPv2C.

The rest of Net-SNMP Agent configuration parameters are described here: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/demon/snmpd.html

Comment: Ok, thanks. What do you thing about my config files?

Comment: They look pretty standard to me

Comment: Do you recommend to add another options?

Comment: I'd suggest changing the default community string from public to something more secure.

Comment: Ok, It's possible to keep endoced password in snmpd.conf?

Comment: No the password is stored as is. The config file by design is not supposed to be visible to non-authorized users.